# Connection to local FTP while using VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, routing, ftp

My computer is connected to the internet through a VPN. I would like to use FTP server (linux) which is connected to my LAN network. I know that the IP of my FTP is 192.168.1.140. I tried to use `route add 192.168.1.140` but it didn't help. I would like to exempt only one IP.

My routing table

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 10...02 50 41 00 20 01 ......PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter
 16...e8 6a 64 b1 66 37 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
  8...48 01 7f c0 61 01 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 13...4a 01 7f c0 61 00 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
  6...48 01 7f c0 61 00 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
 11...48 01 7f c0 61 04 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.100    192.168.1.134     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link        10.1.1.244      1
       10.1.1.244  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.1.244    256
      90.13.33.23  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.100    192.168.1.134     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     172.16.249.4  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.1.244      1
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.134    281
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.1.1.244      1
    192.168.1.134  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.134    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.134    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.1.244    256
    192.168.249.4  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.1.244      1
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.134    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.1.1.244    256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.134    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.1.1.244    256
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: I looks like your local system in Linux, but you should mention that/tag the question explicitly.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Indeed, my FTP server is Linux

Comment: I've meant your *local* machine. – It should not matter what system your *FTP server* runs on, in the context of your question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the machine that is using VPN and from which I want to access FTP is running Windows